# Comparable |sh for Powershell?

Tags: powershell, sh

I have a system where a ton of folks are logging in and getting temporary profiles. So, I want to query the Registry for ".bak" profiles sand then query those results for the C:\Users folders so I can then determine if their folder is there or not.

So far, I have this:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | findstr /i ".bak" | %{$_ -replace "^","reg query """} |%{$_ -replace "$",""" | findstr ProfileImagePath >> d:\temp\Results.dat"}
```

That results in commands like these:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-9876543238-1234562203-7654325021-1001" | findstr ProfileImagePath >> d:\temp\Results.dat
```

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1234563238-1234562203-7654325021-1003" | findstr ProfileImagePath >> d:\temp\Results.dat
```

In the Unix/Linux world, using SED, I could then pipe this to run ( | sh ).
Is there a comparable Powershell call where I can pipe the reformatted command to now run?

Comment: Try `& (reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1234563238-1234562203-7654325021-1003" | findstr ProfileImagePath)`

Comment: The `findstr` command will output something like `ProfileImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\jdoe`. What are you expecting to happen when you do the PowerShell equivalent of piping to `sh`? Open the path in File Explorer? Use `Test-Path` or `Get-Item` to see which paths exist? Please update your question to clarify and please also [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: you can use CIM/WMI to get the local profiles, grab a list of dirs in the `Users` dir, and then compare the two. i am unsure what you actually are trying to do, tho. can you explain the _intent_ of this - not the steps, the _rationale_?

Comment: mklement0, Lee_Dailey: I updated the question. I plan to write each response to a results file. I want to see what user accounts (based on the profile path c:\users\<username>) has a temporary profile so I can investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something something like this.  Pass the key name over the pipe to get-itemproperty, then pick the profileimagepath property with select-object.

```
get-item 'HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*.bak' | 
  get-itemproperty -Name ProfileImagePath | 
  select-object ProfileImagePath


ProfileImagePath
----------------
c:\users\fake
c:\users\fake2
```

Here's a way to use test-path with it:

```
get-item 'HKLM:\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*.bak' |
  get-itemproperty |
  select-object ProfileImagePath, @{name='Exists'; 
  expression={test-path $_.ProfileImagePath}}


ProfileImagePath Exists
---------------- ------
c:\users\fake      True
c:\users\fake2    False
```

Comment: I'm very happy with that, js2010!
If you have time, is there a way to then fold those results to then Test-Path the list of values?  If not, no worries. This gets me where I originally requested.  Thanks, again!